# A problem from distribution theory.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

**Let $f$, $g\in C(\Omega)$, and suppose that $f \neq g$ in $C(\Omega)$. How can we prove that $f \neq g$ as distributions?**

Here's the idea of my proof.

$f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, so they will be locally integrable.

Now, take any $\phi \neq 0 \in D(\Omega)$. Let us suppose that $\langle T_f,\phi\rangle =\langle T_g,\phi \rangle $ and $f\neq g$

$\langle T_f,\phi \rangle = \langle T_g,\phi \rangle$

$\implies \int_\Omega f(x) \phi(x) dx = \int_\Omega g(x) \phi(x) dx$

$\implies \int_\Omega \phi(x)[f(x)-g(x)] dx =0$

i.e., the area under above function is zero.

We know that $\phi$ is non zero, ***we just need to prove that this integral will be zero only when $f(x)-g(x)=0$*** and it will make contradiction to our supposition that $f$ and $g$ are not equal.

**[Please help me prove the last point]**

Comment: This holds $\forall \phi$. Now apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations).

Comment: Do you mean, when $\phi$ is zero?

Comment: But if $\phi$ is zero then how will we prove that f-g=0

Comment: No, your last line holds for every $\phi$. So you can conclude, from the theorem, that $f = g$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah I supposed in the stating that $\phi$ is non zero. Now in the end is it okay to say that $f-g$ must be zero to make integral zero. 

And that will make the contradiction. Right!

Comment: Why did you remove the distribution-theory tag?

Comment: Check out the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add a little more detail to my comment.

You are correct up to the $\int_{\Omega} \phi(x)[f(x)-g(x)]dx = 0$.

Now, for $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x_0 \in \Omega$, let $B_{\varepsilon}(x_0)$ denote the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x_0$. Then, you can find a test function $\psi$ with the following properties:

(i) $\psi(x) > 0 \, \forall x \in B_{\varepsilon}(x_0)$

(ii) $\psi(x) = 0 \, \forall x \notin B_{\varepsilon}(x_0)$

(iii) $\int_{\Omega} \psi = \int_{B_{\varepsilon}(x_0)}\psi = 1.$

Now, choose $\phi = \psi$ and for any $x_0 \in \Omega$
$$
0 = \int_{\Omega} \psi(x)[f(x)-g(x)]dx = \int_{B_{\varepsilon}(x_0)} \psi(x)[f(x)-g(x)]dx \approx f(x_0)-g(x_0)
$$

As $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, the equation is exact, i.e. $f(x_0) - g(x_0) = 0$. Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, $f = g$ in $\Omega$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @alo .
In point one i think we should write $\not=0$ than greater than zero.

Right!

Comment: @alo why did you do this specific construction and how we know that such a function will exist and it will satisfy all above properties (I'm not clear on especially 3rd property).
The statement in question should be true for every test function.

Comment: Yes, this statement holds for every test function. So it holds for this specific one. I chose it b/c it gets us that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$. The construction of it is standard, you can find it in most pde books. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). To get 3, just rescale the function by dividing by its integral.